# How to use a root path with require?

Tags: php, path, require

I have a private section within a site with a folder structure like so

```
www.site.com/privatePath/secretFolder/login.php
```

Then some subfolders eg

```
www.site.com/privatePath/secretFolder/grandmasRecipes/applePie.php
```

There is a shared functions.php alongside the login.php

`www.site.com/privatePath/secretFolder/functions.php` (creates $connection, mysql blah blah)

I have various subfolders and files i wish to connect to functions.php, some created dynamically so the solution should work from any file/folder position whatsoever.

Just to clarify:

Because the same file could be called within different folders I would like it to call the functions.php file not from where the file is but in relation to the root folder. So without relative ../ etc references

my question:
How can i access a required php file from any file within my website?

Comment: Dynamically generated PHP files sounds like a **really bad idea**

Comment: @Phil totally right. It exists because menus and submenus and page links are created via  the file directories. Problem is each page needs to create sessions.

Comment: Even though I think relying on `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a bad idea (for starters, it won't work if your HTTP server doesn't set the property), I don't see a reason why your code wouldn't work. Are you absolutely sure you don't have `require 'functions.php';` in your `applePie.php` script on line #4?

Comment: @Phil, checked spelling 1000 times, stopped 'solving' to ask stackoverflow, returning to page my IDE and i see that i have been editing a old copy arrgggghhhh SORRRYYY MAN, SORRY STACKOVERFLOW and SORRY AND THANKS PHIL. HUMAN ERROR so sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice is **never** rely on any external path configuration (such as `DOCUMENT_ROOT`). Instead, use paths relative to the current script...

From `login.php`

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/functions.php';
```

From `grandmasRecipes/applePie.php`

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../functions.php';
```

See http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php#constant.dir

---

An alternative might be to set the `include_path` for the current environment. You can do this in say a `.user.ini` file in your document root

```
; /home/cpanelLogIn/public_html/.user.ini

include_path="/home/cpanelLogIn/public_html/:."
```

Then you can simply use

```
require_once 'privatePath/secretFolder/functions.php';
```

anywhere

Comment: Thanks Phil, Unfortunately I cannot guarantee which folder the file produced will be called from. So i need a root based solution.

Comment: @Gamemorize I have absolutely no idea what that means

Comment: I mean that because the same file could be called in a different folders I would like it to call the functions.php file not from where the file is but in relation to the root folder

Comment: @Gamemorize I've added an alternative

Comment: Please add to your answer that DOCUMENT_ROOT will work but you have reservations, I will delete it from my question

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
require ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/privatePath/secretFolder/functions.php");
```

Will access functions.php file from any page in site.